# .animate ScrollTop Works but not smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have JQuery code to Animate ScrollTop

Browser scrolls to desired position but not smoothly.

```
function scrollto_aboutUsSection(){
// alert("about us scroll called");
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#aboutUs_section").offset().top }, 0.001);
}
```

And HTML Code is as below

```
<div id="container">

        <?php include("Includes/header&nav.html"); ?>

        <div id="content">

            <?php include("Includes/information_section.html"); ?>

            <section id = "aboutUs_section" class="Section">
                <h2 class="textShadow big_h2_font"> About Us </h2>
                <p class="textShadow">  In 1987, Our founders laid the foundation of jewellery store in Gakhar Plaza, Saddar, Rawalpindi. Since that time we are in service in presentation of artistic jewels by the hands of talented craft persons and skilled artists. We still try our best to come up with ideas that matches with yours most, keeping the eye on craftmanships side by side. We deal in 21K, Embedded and non Embedded Jewels generally.
                </br></br>If you are looking for 22K, we take orders as well.
                </br></br>Visit our Gallery and have a look at our Jewels Range.  </p>
            </section> 
</div> </div>
```

Other Functions call this JQuery Function.

I have Included `<?php ?>` in html code inside body tag. This **JQuery function** calls on page load also. so Isn't the reason that it skips animations smoothly.

Before **PHP**, it was working fine.

Comment: Give it some time to animation `0.001` means almost zero... try `500` for example, which is half a second.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I understood and solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very slow speed. Use this:

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#aboutUs_section").offset().top }, 1000);
```

Notice the last value `1000` instead of your old `0.001`

That's the speed in milliseconds. So 1000 is 1 second.

Comment: Thank you So much. It Helped me.